# How to resolve COM Port Issue through Command Line

Tags: command-line, arduino, usb, port

I am executing the following code on different systems. I require a generalized COMPORT parameter so that the code runs fine on all systems depending on COM PORT involved for that device.

C:\arduino\setup\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\arduino\setup\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P\.**\COM121** -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\XYZ\ABC\files\abc.cpp.hex:i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Windows and want your commands to work on different Windows machines even though the Arduinos are on different COM ports.  Most Arduinos these days use usbser.sys.  If you assume that there is only one device using usbser.sys plugged into the system and that is the Arduino, then the Arduino can be accessed at an object named USBSER000.  You can pass `\\.\USBSER000` as the port argument to AVRDUDE to refer to the Arduino's port.

You have to escape that string properly, so the actual command you write will be something like:

```
avrdude -P\\\\.\\USBSER000 ...
```

Other things that might help you:

- Did you know you can change the port the Arduino is on from the Device Manager?  I prefer to keep all my Arduinos on COM7.
- You can set an environment variable on each machine to say what port the Arduino is on, then refer to it in your commands with something like `%VARNAME%` or `$VARNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the baud rate? Probably it's causing the issue. It's better if you use the lower baud rate possible. Also, the baud rate should match in your code and in the COM Port configuration. (check on the device manager)

Comment: Actually i want to use this command on different systems. but different systems will have different com port like COM121 or COM51 etc. So i need a generalized command so that i don't need to change code at each system

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have access to comments, I'm going to answer *ASSUMING* you're trying this under a WINDOWS operating system.

First, it'd be a bit easier and somewhat more elegant to write a utility program for this request because no one particular setting in your command line can account for all possible COM port setups on varying systems.

Under windows, there's no 'Alias' command to associate a generic name with a config item such as a COM port, so applying a generic name isn't possible. You could write a FOR loop and place that in a CMD or BAT file with logic that attempts to echo text to a list of typical COM port names such as COM1, COM2 etc.

If you type this line in a CMD or command prompt window under MS-DOS or Windows:

```
 echo "This is a test" > COM1:
```

You will either get no response (good) or the OS will reply:

```
 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The latter signals that there is no such device. A FOR-loop could test iterations for the first device that does not return an error. The problem here is that on systems with multiple serial ports (as is common) your code will attempt the FIRST device it finds. If the user connected the serial cable to a different port, it will not work.

**This is why I suggest that you write a utility program. The utility can inventory a list of the available serial ports, then attempt to interrogate each port for the device with a query. This is the only way I know that would guarantee that the 'command line' you want to use would be uniform across all systems.**

Comment: I understand the concept but on my system several ports may be used. for ex COM121 , COM 11 both are used and on testing above command on both of them acknowledges it by giving no response. But how to detect my arduino device is connected to 121 not 11.

Comment: That's why I said writing a utility is the only way to assure you that you have the correct port. If the Arduino can be programmed, I suggest writing a short block of code that responds to an interrogation coming over the port. So on the PC side, you'd send a unique string to the COM port. On the Arduino, you have a listener watching the COM port traffic for that string. When it 'sees' the string, it responds by sending out a reply - or echoes the string itself. The logic in your PC utility sees the response and can notify the calling application, or in this case, the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

David Grayson your answer was awesome. 
I also figured out some solution:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
public class ports 
{
static public void Main ()
{
    var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach(var port in portNames) {
        Console.WriteLine (port);
}
}
}
```

compiled and executed this code through mono C# compiler using commands on command prompt

```
mcs ports.cs
mono ports.exe
```

now ports.exe could be used in any system to retrieve a list of available com ports.